# Laravel Eloquent Update Record if New Price is Lower

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but all the examples I can find don't seem to be doing the job.

In short there are prices for an 'offer' in a table. If there is no price with the parameters create a record (this part is working), if not check if the new price is cheaper, if it is then update the record.

Here is my code:

```
$priceExist = OfferPrice:: 
    where('offer_id', $offer_id, 'AND')
    ->where('personal', $price['personal'], 'AND')
    ->where('status', 1, 'AND')
    ->where('deposit', $price['deposit'], 'AND')
    ->where('duration', $price['duration'], 'AND')
    ->where('mileage', $price['mileage'])->get()->first();

if (!$priceExist) {
    $offerPrice = new OfferPrice($price);
    $offerPrice->save();
} else if ( $price['price'] < $priceExist->price) {
    $priceExist->price = $price['price'];
    $priceExist->save();
}
```

This currently returns an error:

> ErrorException: Illegal offset type in /vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php:775

Which appears to be being caused by `$priceExist->save();`.

Any ideas?

---

I should highlight that the code below does work, but is obviously bad code calling the same record twice:

```
$priceExist = OfferPrice::
    where('offer_id', $offer_id, 'AND')
    ->where('personal', $price['personal'], 'AND')
    ->where('status', 1, 'AND')
    ->where('deposit', $price['deposit'], 'AND')
    ->where('duration', $price['duration'], 'AND')
    ->where('mileage', $price['mileage'])->get()->first();

if (!$priceExist) {
    $offerPrice = new OfferPrice($price);
    $offerPrice->save();
} else if ( $price['price'] < $priceExist->price) {
    OfferPrice::
    where('offer_id', $offer_id, 'AND')
    ->where('personal', $price['personal'], 'AND')
    ->where('status', 1, 'AND')
    ->where('deposit', $price['deposit'], 'AND')
    ->where('duration', $price['duration'], 'AND')
    ->where('mileage', $price['mileage'])
    ->update(['price' => $price['price']]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to directly use `->first()` instead of `->get()->first()`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

That type of error would suggest you are trying to access an array with an array/object.

Although there is not enough information in the question to give a concrete answer, I suspect the contents of `$price['price']` is not what you think it is. It may be worth dumping `$price`

Comment: I have added a second example where the price is updating as expected confirming the price is set. Thanks

Comment: No problem, but I'm confused that is two different things? Where is $price coming from in this first example?

Comment: Price is an array being passed from the controller. In both examples the structure is the same, I've just copied the call to OfferPrice and called update directly. Thanks for helping :)